# Calling IDA Pro through python

Tags: python, linux, bash, ida

I am trying to use a python script to call IDA Pro and have it run in bash mode. Similar to that of the linux terminal line './idal -B input-File' is there a quick and simple way I can do this throughout the python script? I have looked through the IDA Pro book and I can only find information on IDAPython which I am struggling to understand.

Comment: So far I have also attempted to use a shell script to just run all of the calling processes. However I need to prompt the user for the input-file and I am unaware on how I can call a value within the python script from the shell script (if that's possible!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate.

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) answer.

It's basically resumes to:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["./idal", "-B", "input-File"])
```